# Find minimum N elements in theano

Tags: python-2.7, theano

I've got a theano function which computes euclidean distances for 2 matrices—`X` (`n vectors x k features`) and `Y` (`m vectors x k features`). The result is an `n x m` matrix of pairwise distances of each vector (or row) in `X` from each vector (or row) in `Y`.

```
import theano
from theano import tensor as T

X, Y = T.dmatrices('X', 'Y')
X_squared_sum = T.sum(X ** 2, axis=1, keepdims=True)
Y_squared_sum = T.sum(Y.T ** 2, axis=0, keepdims=True)
squared_distances = X_squared_sum + Y_squared_sum - 2 * T.dot(X, Y.T)
f_distance = theano.function([X, Y], T.sqrt(squared_distances))
```

Let's say I change the above function to accept a single vector, an array of vectors, and the number of smallest distances. What I want is a theano function that will find the N smallest distances, similar to below:

```
import numpy as np
import theano
from theano import tensor as T

X = T.dvector('X')
Y = T.dmatrix('Y')
N = T.iscalar('N')
X_squared_sum = T.dot(X, X)
Y_squared_sum = T.sum(Y.T ** 2, axis=0)
squared_distances = X_squared_sum + Y_squared_sum - 2 * T.dot(X, Y.T)
dist_sorted = T.FIND_N_SMALLEST(T.sqrt(squared_distances), N)
n_closest = theano.function([X, Y, N], dist_sorted)

U = np.array([[1, 1, 1, 1]])
V = np.array([
      [  4,   4,   4,   4],
      [  2,   2,   2,   2],
      [  3,   3,   3,   3],
      [  1,   1,   1,   1]])

n_closest(U, V, 2)  # [0.0, 2.0]
```

I'd like to avoid explicitly sorting all the distances, since the number that I want will generally be much much smaller than the total number of distances.

Comment: So the numpy equivalent of what you are looking for is probably `numpy.argpartition`, which is not available in theano. What you do have is `T.argsort` but as far as I understand, you don't want to use that. Before spending too much time trying to optimize this: Is that really your bottleneck?